# What is "Smooth Manifold" in Differential Topology?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am recently studying Differential Topology from the Milnor's book. I have some questions regarding smooth manifolds and smooth maps. Can I say the followings:

Are smooth manifolds equivalent to the ringed spaces which are locally identical to the ringed space with smooth functions ?

Please help me. Thanking you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The category of smoothly embedded submanifolds of Euclidean space is equivalent to the category of abstract smooth manifolds because every smooth manifold can be embedded (this uses Hausdorff+paracompactness).

The category of abstract smooth manifolds and smooth maps is equivalent to the full subcategory of locally $\mathbb R$-ringed spaces spanned by the following objects: locally $\mathbb R$-ringed spaces which admit an open cover on which they are isomorphic (in the category of locally $\mathbb R$-ringed spaces) to an open subset of Euclidean space equipped with its sheaf of smooth real valued functions.